# Use 32bit shared library from 64bit application?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I have created a simple linux 32bit shared library(.so) for my rendering wrappers but i've hit a wall when i figured that i can only
use them through 32bit applications....................

This is how my code looks like:

RendIFace.h:

```
//Basic renderer interface
struct Renderer
{
    int type;
    ...other things
};
```

GLRend.c:

```
#include "RendIFace.h"
struct Renderer* GLRendererCreate(int width,int height,int bytesPerPixel)
{
    struct Renderer* rend = (struct Renderer*)malloc(sizeof(Renderer));

    rend->type = GLR;
    ..other things

    return rend;
}
```

SDLRend.c:

```
#include "RendIFace.h"
struct Renderer* SDLRendererCreate(int width,int height,int bytesPerPixel)
{
    struct Renderer* rend = (struct Renderer*)malloc(sizeof(Renderer));

    rend->type = SDLR;
    ..other things

    return rend;
}
```

And i compile both as shared 32bit libraries(.so) and load them through the main application...

But now there is a big problem.My libraries are all 32bit and return 32bit pointers which means that i can't use them through 
an 64bit application without rebuilding all the library code base(!!!).

So i would like to ask more experienced people : How do i handle this issue ? Is it possible to use just a single shared library for both architectures ???

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. A DLL/SO is loaded *into* the programs process. I've never seen/heard of it work when the bitness differs (as the 32-bit IA32 is now trying to run in a 64-bit AMD64 context and, among other things, the CC likely differs).

Comment: Are you also writting the application? or just the lib?

Comment: Im writing both the app and lib...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must be consistent.  A 64-bit application can only use 64-bit libraries and a 32-bit application can only use 32-bit libraries.  Both work; either choice is fine, and it's possible to compile the same code for both systems.

If you go for 'all 32-bit', use:

- `gcc -m32`

If you go for 'all 64-bit', use:

- `gcc -m64`

Sometimes, I'll tell `make` that the C compiler is `gcc -m32` (or `-m64`) rather than just `gcc` to ensure the right value is used everywhere.

Comment: Thank you.I guess i should switch to static libraries then.

Comment: Whether you use static or shared libraries, you will still have to be consistent and build them either all 32-bit or all 64-bit.  You can't mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in a single executable.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do what you're asking. You must compile both the final executable and any libraries (both static and shared) for the same architecture.

On GCC, this can be done easily by passing the command line argument `-m32` either directly in the command line or by adding it `CCFLAGS` in your `Makefile`.

While it is possible to run x86 code on a x86_64 operating system (you just need to have all the right libraries and their respective recursive dependencies), you cannot, in one executable or in one address space, combine x86 and x86_64 binaries.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Even static libraries are compiled for either 64 or 32 bit.