# Problems restarting Apache Server

Tags: linux, apache, centos

Well, I'm having some problems restarting my Apache Server. I modified the ulimit on the server but I'm failing to restart httpd;
I'm running the server on `CentOS 5.8 x64`. The output from httpd -V:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Jan 10 2013 08:19:28
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:3
Server loaded:  APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Compiled using: APR 1.2.7, APR-Util 1.2.7
Architecture:   64-bit
```

The error I'm getting when running `/sbin/service httpd restart`(I'm not going to print the hall output):

```
Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf: 
Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: libidn.so.11: 
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I googled this error and tried to dig for the problem. What I found is that `libphp5.so` is 64-bit architecture whilst `libidn.so.11` is 32-bit. Normally, as I know, there shouldn't be a problem using 32-bit programs on 64-bit architecture, but in this case there's 32-bit library used in 64-bit program(****See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039401/use-32bit-shared-library-from-64bit-application)**).

I tried to install the 64-bit version of the library but what I could find, for my O.S.(`centOS 5.8`) is the libidn_x86_64 version, which is again on 32-bit.

Programs installed on server:

```
squid - Proxy
ffmpeg - for video streaming
csf-lfd -> firewall
Apache
```

Any help on finding the problem is appreciated!

Comment: Cent Os 5.8 is too old Can't you update it to 6.4?. Always take a back up of the conf file before making any changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [version of libidn in CentOS 5.1](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libidn&submit=Search%20...&system=Centos&arch=) is the same as in 5.9 (indeed it's the same file), it's probably a safe bet that it will install in 5.8

> could find, for my O.S.(centOS 5.8) is the libidn_x86_64 version, which is again on 32-bit.

No, the name implies it's the 64 bit version - if it contains a 32 bit object file, then something has gone way wrong - further, given the wide usage of CentOS and that libidn is required for all sorts of things, I'm sure someone would have noticed by now if the rpm contained the wrong file.

You might want to spend some time thinking about how your server got into this state. It shouldn't have been possible to install/upgrade the PHP from Centos respoitories with the right dependencies in place (unless you forced it to ignore them).

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question. I tried to uninstall libidn with `yum remove libidn`. After this command it asks me if it's ok to remove `libidn` with it's dependencies. Actually what I found strange is that it's going to remove libidn i386 and libidn x86_64 (both having the version 0.6.5-1.1 ). Is it okay to uninstall the packages and then install manually only the x86_64 via rpm? Thanks

Comment: That should not be necessary - either the previous installation is broken (in which case, just reinstall the x86_64 package) or your ld config is broken.

Comment: Yes, that did it! I spend the hall day fixing this and `yum reinstall libidn` simply did it... Anyway, Thank you!