# getting error when running shard object that compiled with 32 bit flag on 64 bit system :PAM unable to dlopen my_pam.so wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: ubuntu, dll, linker, pam

I compile pam hook based in the interface with this compilation flag's:

```
gcc -O0 -g -m32  -I/ext -I/inc -MD -MP -c -DARCH=x86 -o my_pam.o my_pam.c
 cat /etc/pam.d/sshd
account     optional      /root/my_pam.so
session     optional      /root/my_pam.so
auth        optional      /root/my_pam.so
password    optional      /root/my_pam.so
```

The code my_pam.c:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define PAM_OK 0
#define PAM_ERROR -1    
/*PAM defintion */
#define PAM_SM_AUTH
#define PAM_SM_ACCOUNT
#define PAM_SM_SESSION
#define PAM_SM_PASSWORD 
/*PAM includes */
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include <security/pam_modutil.h>
#include <security/pam_ext.h>


/* The actual pam functions are merely wrappers around succeed_if */
PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {

        return (PAM_SUCCESS);
}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS;

}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_chauthtok(pam_handle_t    *pamh,const int flags,int argc,const char **argv)
{
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}


PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS;

}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_open_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

    PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_close_session(pam_handle_t *pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv) {
        return PAM_SUCCESS;
    }
```

and when i try to login via ssh i can't login and the log file /var/log/auth.log
tel's me that error :
 PAM unable to dlopen /root/my_pam.so wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
I guess it is because I am on a 64 bit ubuntu and compiled with 32 bit flag (which is what I want), I did install sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev:i386
in order to have also the pam library for 32 bit but it seems that pam still looking for it's 64 bit version. How do I fix this and make ubuntu use my 32 bit pam?

Answer (score 0):

you can't , i found this answer here [Use 32bit shared library from 64bit application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039401/use-32bit-shared-library-from-64bit-application?rq=1)
and after several tries and go through couple of other question's you just can't compile it and use 32 bit with 64 bit code together .